# Why Django couldn't find an object with given slug?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django tells that the object with given slug could not be found (i.e. 404 code). Though queryset returned isn't empty

```
class PollDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = PollSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs['pk']
        print(Poll.objects.filter(slug=slug)) # Prints '<QuerySet [<Poll: ddd>]>' reaching '/api/poll/ddd/' url
        return Poll.objects.filter(slug=slug) # 404 Not Found
```

Comment: `.filter()` on its own will not return a `404`. There must something wrong you did not show us, maybe the routing.

Answer (score 0):

add look_up field in your `PollDetailView`

```
look_up = 'slug'
```

and in your `urls.py`

change `PollDetailView` url to

```
url(r'^api/polls/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.PollDetail.as_view(),name='poll-detail'),
```